# Threadsafe Cython RNG nogil Parallelization

Tags: python, numpy, random, thread-safety, cython

I'm attempting to generate random numbers inside a `nogil` `prange` loop in Cython by extending `numpy.random` RNGs. I'm attempting to use [this](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/random/extending.html#cython) example, and combine it with intuitions from [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/bit_generators/pcg64.html) to create separate bit generators for each thread to avoid locking requirements. I am clearly misunderstanding something, however, as the `bitgen_t` entity's `state` and memory location are the same across what I assumed would be different bit generators with independent states. The result is that, e.g., when generating 1000 random numbers in this way, there are something like 40% duplicate numbers (which makes sense, given there is only actually one bit generator being used). When generating large amounts of random numbers, it also segfaults, which I imagine is related.

**If there is an easier way to do this, let me know!**

Here is current code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#cython: language_level=3
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cpython.pycapsule cimport PyCapsule_IsValid, PyCapsule_GetPointer
from cython.parallel import prange, threadid
from numpy.random import PCG64, SeedSequence, Generator
from numpy.random cimport bitgen_t
from libc.stdlib cimport malloc, free
from libc.stdint cimport uintptr_t


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def uniforms(Py_ssize_t n):
    """
    Create an array of `n` uniformly distributed doubles.
    A 'real' distribution would want to process the values into
    some non-uniform distribution
    """
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, thid
    cdef const char *capsule_name = "BitGenerator"
    cdef double[:] random_values = np.ones(n, dtype='float64') * -1.

    # Create an RNG for each thread so we don't have to lock them.
    cdef Py_ssize_t num_threads = 16
    capsules = [Generator(PCG64(s)).bit_generator.capsule for s in SeedSequence(1234).spawn(num_threads)]

    cdef bitgen_t **rngs_c

    try:
        # Cast capsules into ptr array for use outside of gil.
        rngs_c = <bitgen_t**>malloc(num_threads * sizeof(bitgen_t*))
        for i, capsule in enumerate(capsules):
            if not PyCapsule_IsValid(capsule, capsule_name):
                raise ValueError("Invalid pointer to anon_func_state")
            rngs_c[i] = <bitgen_t *> PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, capsule_name)
            print(<uintptr_t>rngs_c[i])

        with nogil:
            for i in prange(n, schedule="static", num_threads=num_threads):
                thid = threadid()
                rng = rngs_c[thid]
                random_values[i] = rng.next_double(rng.state)
    finally:
        free(rngs_c)

    return np.asarray(random_values)
```

If I run this as is, I get this output (note the `print(<uintptr_t>rngs_c[i])` that prints the address of the `bitgen_t` as retrieved from the different capsules.

```py
>>> x = uniforms(1000)
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
4931169440
>>> np.unique(x).size
594
```

Note that compiling this (and observing issues related to parallelization) requires compiling with openmp. Details can be found [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html#compiling).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the possibility to check my assumption right now, but my guess is that you have dangling pointers due to:

```
[Generator(PCG64(s)).bit_generator.capsule for s in SeedSequence(1234).spawn(num_threads)]
```

getting hold of the capsule doesn't keep the generator alive, which gets deleted directly after its creation, the freed memory gets reused by the next temporary generator, thus all `capsule`s have the same address.

So you have to keep generator in a list, so they are alive as long as you use `capsule`s:

```
 generators = [Generator(PCG64(s)) for s in SeedSequence(1234).spawn(num_threads)]
 capsules = [g.bit_generator.capsule for g in generators]
```

If my assumption is wrong, I will delete this answer.

Comment: YAY. That was it. Thank you very very much!